# Should we burninate the [lfs] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

I try to answer Linux From Scratch questions when I can. I've run through the book several times over the years, and know it pretty well. So, I search for questions with the [lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lfs) tag. Lately, however, I'm finding lots of questions tagged [lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lfs) that are really related to Git LFS. I've edited about 20 questions now to change the [lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lfs) tag to [git-lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-lfs).

We could eliminate a lot of confusion by burninating [lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lfs) and replacing its usage with [linux-from-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-from-scratch), a tag that already exists.

I'm fine with continuing to edit these questions. I get 2 points every time I do, but seems like making this problem just go away would be the better choice.

I'm open to other suggestions, even "ignore it—on the grand scheme of things it doesn't really happen all that often".

Comment: Can we make [lfs] a synonym of [linux-from-scratch]? Because [ifs] is shorthand and people prefer to use it more often.

Comment: @weegee people rarely prefer anything. They allow the system to suggest tags.

Comment: Then making it a synonym seems to be a prudential decision. @Braiam

Comment: The system doesn't suggest you a synonym @weegee, it suggest you the tag itself.

Comment: You said in your previous comment that people allow the system to suggest tags then why there were git questions in [lfs]? If we make [lfs] a synonym of [linux-from-scratch] then I don't think there will be more confusion and more questions like that in [linux-from-scratch] tag. The [git-lfs] tag speaks for itself

Comment: This isn’t a burnination. It is a simple rename of a tag. This looks like an obviously good idea. I’ll pull the trigger soon if no objections materialize. Once that’s done, you or anyone else could go through and clean up the questions that were incorrectly tagged. (Note that, when retagging, you should also fix all other problems with a question, including spelling, grammar, formatting, removing tags from the title, etc.)

Comment: @CodyGray a little confused. Are we renaming the [lfs] tag? I would also like to help out in editing the questions and retagging them.

Comment: Yes, it seems you are suggesting that the [lfs] tag be renamed to [linux-from-scratch]. The "straggler" questions could then be manually retagged and cleaned up.

Comment: @CodyGray except that the linux-from-scratch tag *already exists*. So this is really a [meta-tag:synonym-request]

Answer (score 5):

The tag should have been a synonym for [linux-from-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-from-scratch), all remaining questions with the tag were all on that subject already.

I’ve merged the tag into [linux-from-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-from-scratch), and left the synonym in place. So anyone using [lfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lfs) from now on will see [linux-from-scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux-from-scratch) in the tagging UI and the latter tag will be used if they still use the old tag name.